# Duplicated data in two different objects in python

Tags: python, memory, duplicates

can anyone help me with s strange problem?

https://travis-ci.org/ezored/ezored/jobs/322719711

On test log, i print:

> Current data:
>   ['flag']
>   ['flag']

That is the lines:

```
new_target_data.c_flags.extend(['flag'])

print('Current data:')
print(target_data.c_flags)
print(new_target_data.c_flags)
```

The problem is when i extend **"new_target_data.c_flags"**. The same data is applied to **"target_data.c_flags"**. They are different objects, you can see on log the memory reference:

```
<ezored.models.target_data.TargetData object at 0x2b59c0673590>
<ezored.models.target_data.TargetData object at 0x2b59c0673510>
```

The file with test code is here (method **test_merge_target_data**):

https://github.com/ezored/ezored/blob/issue_1/tests/models/test_target.py#L76

Anyone understand this problem? What im doing wrong?

Comment: More than likely one of them is a shadow copy of the other, please provide how these items are defined.

Comment: Hi. It was on post link. Only need click to go to the full file. But it was already answered.

Comment: We should not need to look into your entire code base for something that you can easily define in the question. I asked you to provide them inside the question because questions should be self-contained.

Comment: Ok man, dont worry. I think i was typed everything to everyone understand. The user "schwobaseggl" understand in this mode that i put and solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into that code base, you will find the following class:

```
class TargetData(object):
    # ...
    c_flags = []
    # ...
```

As you see, `c_flags` is a **class attribute** of this class. Both `new_target_data` and `target_data` are instances of this class, and expectedly, accessing `c_flags` will always produce the same object. Instead of showing the two instances' mem location, you should show the actual object that you are mutating, `c_flags`

```
print(id(new_target_data.c_flags))
print(id(target_data.c_flags))
```

and you will see they are the same.

Comment: You are correct man. I made a sample here: https://repl.it/repls/GainsboroClutteredXiphiasgladius. This rule is applied to list and dict. Integer and String is not treaded as instance variables. Thanks.